# TypeError: expected string

Tags: python

The output of the data shows as `('ABC\n', 0)` from the names.txt file How can I print it as `ABC` The `name.txt` are German names

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import os
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
filepath = 'names.txt'
fonttype = '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial.ttf'
fntYU = ImageFont.truetype(fonttype, 150)
i=0
with open(filepath) as myfile:
    for data in zip(myfile, range(100)):
        i+=1
        print (data)
        if i == 100:
            os.system("echo complete the 10 photots > complete.txt")
        if (len(data)) <= 6:
            img = Image.new('RGB', (3840, 2160), color = (255, 255, 255))
            fnt = ImageFont.truetype(fonttype, 550)
            d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
            d.text((600,700), data, font=fnt, fill=(0, 0, 0))
            img.save(data.replace('\n', '')+".png")
```

The Error:

```
('ABC\n', 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "imagesv2.py", line 24, in <module>
    d.text((600,700), data, font=fnt, fill=(0, 0, 0))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/ImageDraw.py", line 220, in text
    mask, offset = font.getmask2(text, self.fontmode, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 181, in getmask2
    size, offset = self.font.getsize(text, direction, features)
TypeError: expected string
```

Comment: Why are you using `zip` in the first place?

Comment: And the error in the question title isn't mentioned in your question

Comment: if you have a line break in your `name.txt`, it is normal that it shows on `print`. If you remove it and you are willing to save your output in a txt file, it may not show the result you want. Please clarify what you really want at the end: only a neat `print` or a correct text output ?

Comment: Yes, `data` is a `tuple`, which is what `zip` objects produces from their iterators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whats the need of using `zip`?
This should work -

```
import os
filepath = 'names.txt'
with open(filepath, 'r') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        print(line.rstrip('\n'))
```

EDIT: If you want to break after 100 lines use `enumerate`. For example-.

```
for index, line in enumerate(f):
  print(line)
  if index >= 100:
    break
```

Comment: I used zip just to break the loop when I read the first 100 names/lines

Comment: @user1448371 Check the edit. You can use enumerate to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import sys
filepath = 'names.txt'
i=0
with open(filepath) as myfile:
    for data in myfile:
        i+=1
    print (data.strip())
```

Comment: That's great, but how can I break the loop I want to read the first 100 names only, that's why I used zip in the first place.

Comment: To help others understand your answer, consider including a short description of your code and how it solves the posted question